# Get subclass Rectangle2D.Double member via JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Assume following class

```
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

class SomeJavaClass
{
    public SomeJavaClass()
    {
        m_rect = new Rectangle2D.Double();
    }
    Rectangle2D.Double m_rect;
}
```

and following C++ code

```
jclass someJavaCls = env->FindClass("my/package/SomeJavaClass");
jfieldID rectID = env->GetFieldID(someJavaCls, "m_rect", "Ljava/awt/geom/Rectangle2D;");
```

The problem is that I don't know how to access the fieldID for the `m_rect`. With the above `GetFieldID` call I get

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: m_rect
```

But also if I change the signature of `GetFieldID` to `"Ljava/awt/geom/Rectangle2D/Double;"` I get the same exception. How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution seems to be "Ljava/awt/geom/Rectangle2D$Double;" since `Double` is a subclass of `Rectangle2D`.